# What does a Swing Call mean?

Tags: java, swing

I have a project that takes time to load everything so I create a splash screen that tells the user through a progressbar how much time it will take to fully load and show the UI, but I'm facing a problem.

When I create my splash, this shows up correctly but then I create and initialize the Principal frame and everything freeze until this has fully load.

So, I try to load my Principal frame in a thread using `SwingWorker` (and it works) but after unknown `NullPointerException`s and reading a lot I found that this is a **terrible** idea because I am not creating my UI in the EDT, so here I am stuck.

I know that I must do Swing Calls in the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) and non-swing heavy work in SwingWorkers but initialize the Swing Components of my Principal Frame are a heavy work too so, what should I do?

I have read some question here, specially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2364852/3998458), and I think I get it but I have doubts. Taking that example:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new SplashScreen();
    }
});
// Code to start system (nothing that touches the GUI)
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new MainFrame();
    }
});
//.. etc
```

And reading [this site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/swingworker-137249.html) that says:

> The Swing framework manages component drawing, updates, and event handlers on the EDT.

Is creating a new component a Swing Call? If it is, What should I do if `new MainFrame()` will take some time because the project has a lot of components to initialize?

How do I tell the Splash something like "Program loaded 50%"?

What does a Swing Call means and how can I do a correct use of `invokeLater` and `SwingWorker`? Maybe the solution is too obvious or have already an answer, but I can't see it and I apologize if this is the case.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a catch 22 problem.  You need to find away to load as much of the none-visual content as possible outside of the EDT (using something like a `SwingWorker`).  You can not guarantee when a component might become realised (attached to a native peer and hence start generating events)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on a right track. But don't use `invokeAndWait` (if you have to only) - use `invokeLater`:

**invokeAndWait**

> Causes doRun.run() to be executed **synchronously** on the AWT event dispatching thread.

**invokeLater**

> Causes doRun.run() to be executed **asynchronously** on the AWT event dispatching thread.

Consider that block wrapped `doLater` is run on EDT thread and code wrapped in `doOutside` is invoked in another thread (and that's why you don't block the UI):

**EDIT**:

As pointed out in the comments I add the explanations for the concepts I'll use.

---

```
doLater {
    // here goes the code
}
```

is a concept for:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // here goes the code
    }
});
```

And

```
doOutside {
    // here goes the code
}
```

is a concept for:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // here goes the code
    }
}).start();
```

---

```
doLater {
    final MainFrame m = new MainFrame();
    doOutside {
        // handle heavy operation
        final int result = 1;
        doLater {
            m.setResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Conclusion: everything that touches Swing in some way must be run on EDT.
If you want to update percentages:

```
doLater {
    final MainFrame m = new MainFrame();
    doOutside {
        // handle progress
        for(int i = 0; i < someSize; ++i) {
            final int progress = i;
            doLater {
                m.getProgressBar().setProgress(progress);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I hope you understand the concept now. The SwingWorker just do exectly something as `doOutside` === `doInBackground` & `doLater` === `done`/`progress`

Btw. The code above is a real code: lookup [`Griffon`](https://github.com/griffon/griffon) framework in Groovy.

Comment: I personally feel that Groovy makes stuff like easier, but aren't you at least slightly worried that springing a new language on the OP might make this answer hard to follow, the question is after all tagged `java`

Comment: I agree with MadProgrammer.  If new MainFrame() is really taking that long, then your best bet is to figure out what (non-visual) components you can move *out*, and call in a separate thread.  Once the UI components are initialized (which *should* be able to happen very quickly), then you can easily display a visual "status bar" for any subsequent initialization.

Comment: I also agree with Jason Sperske: Groovy is Good ... but the immediate problem is a *Java* problem - minimize the work needed to get your initial UI complete and your Event Loop running.

Comment: The `doLater` and `doOutside` is just an abstraction of `doInBackground` & `done` - just to get the concept. It would be a really long code if I've written it in SwingWokers :)

Comment: with MadProgrammer suggestion and your answers, I guess I'm now start to getting it. I'll do some test to learn how to separate swing and non-swing stuffs and then, try to apply this example.

Comment: @Xeon, after a long re-edit to the project, even with this chances, I still having a considerable delay loading all my swing components and my splash is still getting freezed, so I remove it from my principal project and made another that include only the splash. So I ended with two process and I communicate both with the java.net libraries (using sockets), now both can run independently (with 2 jvm), Is this a bad idea?